# create a shell who download a file on dropfile.to with curl

Tags: linux, shell, curl, download, sh

It's my 1st question here, so be gentle ;-)
I search how write a shell who can download a file from dropfile.to with curl

Context: We exchange videos we took with our GoPro with dropfile.to instead of cut them and send them by mail.
We don't need any registration but this website keep the videos during 24 hours before delete them automatically.
So, I write a shell who read my mail (done) and download automatically a video when it find a dropfile.to link...

For now, I know when I press the button "dowload file" on dropfile.to/$code, I send a POST request with the parameter dl_file_name  : "$code"; the website do a redirection and do a GET request; the file I want is in the header answer as a file attachment...

so the curl request should be something like:

```
curl -L -O -J -d download-file:$code https://dropfile.to/$code
```

with options:
 -L for the redirection
 -O for download the result
 -J for download the attachment file
 -d for the POST method

Sadly, it not work... T_T

and when i use directly the get URL i found in my browser like:

```
curl -O -J $urlGet
```

i have some erors like:

```
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0    337      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   337
100   154  100   154    0     0    139      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3080
Warning: Remote filename has no length!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 3445)
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

In `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, names and values are separated with equal symbol (`=`) :

```
code="p42zvEV"
curl -L -J -O "https://dropfile.to/$code" -d "dl_file_name=$code"
```